# Google chrome does not show Nimbus Roman No9 L font

Tags: fonts, google-chrome

Well, to begin with  Here's webpage: http://seedconference.com/seed.php

Here's its CSS:

```
p {
font-family: times, Times New Roman, times-roman, georgia, serif;
}
```

Here's alias:

```
$ fc-match times

n021003l.pfb: "Nimbus Roman No9 L" "Regular"
```

Firefox shows everything as it should be, but Chrome shows in Liberation Serif.

I tried to play with Chrome's font settings. But it didn't change anything.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be using Times Roman for me. Perhaps I'm running a later version?

Here is a suggestion for tracking down the problem. Run chrome with the FC_DEBUG environment variable set. Then you can see what fonts it is using.

```
FC_DEBUG=1 google-chrome http://seedconference.com/seed.php > ~/Desktop/Out
```

saved all the fonts accessed into ~/Desktop/Out. I find

```
grep file: ~/Desktop/Out
```

useful for listing the fonts actually used.